How to show $ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 +dy^2}{1+x^2 +y^2}$ is a soliton of normalized Ricci flow?
Picture below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this). In this paper, the author consider the normalized Ricci flow
$$
\partial_t g_{ij} = (r-R) g_{ij} \tag{1}
$$
where $r$ is the average value of $R$. I want to show the red line. Namely to show
$$
ds^2= \frac{dx^2 +dy^2}{1+x^2 +y^2}  
~~~\text{namely}~~~
g(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{1+x^2 +y^2}  & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{1+x^2 +y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{2}
$$
is a soliton of the normalized Ricci flow.
I've been bored with this question for days.   And in my calculation, (2) is soliton of Ricci flow. Really bad.
What I do: From Wiki I find the vector field of the soliton is
$$
V(x,y)= -2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} -2y \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\tag{3}
$$
Then,  the flow of the vector field is
$$
\phi_t(x,y) = (xe^{-2t}, y e^{-2t})
\tag{4}
$$
Then, let
$$
g(t,x,y) = (\phi_t^* g)(x,y)  
\tag{5}
$$
there is
$$
g(t,x,y) =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{e^{4t}+x^2 +y^2}  & 0  \\
0 & \frac{1}{e^{4t}+x^2 +y^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{6}
$$
Then, I have
$$
R(g(t,x,y)) =\frac{4e^{4t}}{e^{4t}+x^2+y^2}
\tag{7}
$$
Since $n=2$, the Ricci flow is
$$
\partial_t g_{ij} =-2R_{ij} =-Rg_{ij} 
\tag{8}
$$
Obviously, $g(t,x,y)$ and $R(g(t,x,y))$ satisfy (8). So, $g(t,x,y)$ is a steady soliton of Ricci flow.
Since in the picture below, the author say "dilation", I try to change (5) to
$$
\hat g(t,x,y) = \sigma(t)(\phi_t^* g)(x,y) 
\tag{9}
$$
I can get $\sigma(t)$ from $r$ is constant. But  $\hat g$ fail to satisfy (1).  I guess (3) should be changed. But I don't know what is the right vector field.




Use polar coordinates. Asymptotically the metric becomes $d\theta^2$.

@TheAlertGerbil  Thanks. I have to go to class. Let me think it when I have time. I'm not familiar with the metric transformation under this coordinate transformation.

See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729810/352271

@TheAlertGerbil Really good ; )

@TheAlertGerbil  Could you give a detail process of showing it is soliton?  After some days, I still be catched by this problem.
